# I have an integral which I have used contour integration to calculate it. But it seems that I have some contradiction here?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate this integral using residue theorem:
$$
lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{d}\omega\frac{\omega^2-k^2v_F^2}{(\omega+kv+i\epsilon)(\omega-kv-i\epsilon)}\frac{1}{(\omega-kv_q+i\epsilon)(\omega-kv_q-i\epsilon)}
$$

It seems to me that the integrand is proportional to $\frac{1}{\omega^2}$, so it should be convergent at infinity in both upper complex plane and lower complex plane. But if I close the contour in the upper half plane, I got
$$
\frac{i\pi(v_F^2-v^2)}{kv(v-v_q)^2}+\frac{v_F^2-v_q^2}{v_q^2-v^2}\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}
$$
and when I close the contour in the lower half plane, I got
$$
\frac{i\pi(v_F^2-v^2)}{kv(v+v_q)^2}+\frac{v_F^2-v_q^2}{v_q^2-v^2}\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}
$$
My question is why these two results do not coincide?

Comment: You need to specify whether your are approaching zero from the left or the right. Otherwise you do not know what poles you have to consider for your calculations.

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$ and we are approaching zero from the right $\epsilon \to 0+$

Hence, we have four poles $w_1 = -kv -i\epsilon$, $w_2 = kv + i\epsilon$, $w_3 = kv_q -i\epsilon$, $w_4 = kv_q + i\epsilon$

So, if you choose your contour in the upper half plane you only have to consider $w_2$ and $w_4$ for your calculations.